# Devise Route being skipped when called

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, routes

My devise routes were working fine until I implemented a bootstrap theme. Now, it is skipping over the logout route for devise as if it isn't being called. I am a bit confused by this. Here is a partial of my route file:

/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  ######################
  ###     Pages      ###
  ######################

  root to: "pages#home"
  
  get 'about-us',   as: 'about_us',       to: 'pages#about'
  get 'status',     as: 'about_status',   to: 'pages#status'
  get 'verify',     as: 'verify_status',  to: 'pages#verify'
  get 'contact-us', as: 'contact_us',     to: 'pages#contact'


  ######################
  ###    Members     ###
  ######################
  
  devise_for :members, 
              controllers: {
                sessions: 'members/sessions',
                registrations: 'members/registrations'
              },
              path: '', path_names: { 
                  sign_in:    'login', 
                  sign_out:   'logout', 
                  sign_up:    'register',
                  edit:       ':username/account/edit'
              }
              
  get 'cancel_membership',      as: 'cancel_membership',  to: 'pages#cancel'
  

  ###############################
  ###   Ministries & Projects ###
  ###############################
  
  resources :ministries,  except: [:index, :show]
  resources :projects,    except: [:index, :show]

  get 'ministries',                   as: 'ministries_index',  to: 'ministries#index'
  get 'ministry-projects',            as: 'projects_index',    to: 'projects#index'
  get ':ministry',                    as: 'ministry_page',     to: 'ministries#show'
  get ':ministry/:project',           as: 'project_page',      to: 'projects#show'
end
```

As you can see, the Devise routes are declared first, so if a person goes to root_path/logout, it should be handled by the Devise controller of Members; specifically `members/sessions#destroy`.

When I do `rake routes`, I see this (partial):

```
    new_member_session GET    /login(.:format)     members/sessions#new
        member_session POST   /login(.:format)     members/sessions#create
destroy_member_session DELETE /logout(.:format)    members/sessions#destroy
```

....

```
ministries_index GET    /ministries(.:format)                  ministries#index
  projects_index GET    /ministry-projects(.:format)           projects#index
   ministry_page GET    /:ministry(.:format)                   ministries#show
    project_page GET    /:ministry/:project(.:format)          projects#show
```

So, I know that it is processing the routes correctly and in the right order. When I call `destroy_member_session` with either `_path` or `_url` at the end, the browser does show the link for `localhost:3000/logout`. So, that is working and calling the right route.

Code in view being used:

```
<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_member_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

When the link is clicked though, according to the information in the terminal, it shows as being handled by `ministries#show`; as it is the catch all route for anything after root_path that is not previously caught by another route. And if there is no ministry, then an error is displayed stating that no ministry is found (This is the on screen error that I am getting).

To test this further, I deleted the ministry routes so the catchall was deleted. When I try to go to logout, I get an error stating: `No route matches [GET] "/logout"`.

This now tells me that it is not seeing the `method: :delete` being added to the `link_to` as it is trying a `[GET]` not a `[DELETE]`.

I tried changing `method: :delete` to `:method => :delete`, and same result. I read online that maybe a javascript for bootstrap or Jquery was interfering to prevent `[DELETE]` requests. I tried deleting the calls for all javascript and css files and still same result.

I am at a loss now, and can really use some help.

## Putting rubber ducky down on the computer and stepping away now as explaining it in this question didn't provide the solution.

Comment: can you confirm `rails_ujs` or `jquery_ujs` is present in your `application.js`?

Comment: Arrgggg... I knew that with Rails 5.1, `rails_ujs` was moved into Rails itself and was no longer needed. But, I didn't put `//= require jquery_ujs` in the `application.js` file. Thank you, @AneesMuhammed!!!! That is the answer. If you want to write the answer, I will mark it.

Comment: Glad that I could help. I've added the answer!@Christopher Warrington

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've mentioned, your `method: :delete` is not working, You might have missed `jquery_ujs` or `rails_ujs` (rails 5.1+) from your `application.js`. Adding it there if not will make it work.